# Catch all with Next routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I am using the [Next routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-routes) package with configuration like this:

```
routes
  .add(`/:locale`, 'index')
  .add(`/:locale/blog/:slug`, 'blogPost')
  .add(`/:locale/case-studies/:slug`, 'caseStudy')
  .add(`/:locale/services/:slug`, 'service');
```

After defining the routes above I want all other URLs to route to the file `page`.

I tried adding this:

```
.add(`/:locale/*`, 'page');
```

Then tried going to `mydomain.com/en/about` and `mydomain.com/en/about/who-we-are` but this doesn't work. Is there a way to implement a wildcard route like this with Next routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.add(`/:locale/:slug*`, 'page');
```

Comment: @coop maybe just `.add('/:locale*', 'page');` will do the job

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your original answer worked for me, thanks!